Overriding Visual Studio Code file watcher exclusions
In a multi-root code-workspace file's settings block, I have the following watcher exclusion:
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "build/**": true,
}

This works as expected: it avoids watching any files in the build directory or its children.  This setting was added because otherwise it complained about watching too many files on Linux.
However, there's one particular file buried deep within this directory that I actually would like it to be watching.  I have not found any way to successfully "un-exclude" that file.  Attempts included:
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "build/**": true,
    "build/**/InterestingFile": false,
}

(tried both before and after), or:
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "build/**": true,
},
"files.watcherInclude": [
    "build/**/InterestingFile",
],

What is the correct way of doing that?  Or is this a bug?
(For additional context: the file in question is a unit test executable that I want the C++ TestMate extension to notice has changed when I build it.  This works as expected if I comment out the exclusion but not in any other case.  But this seems like a more general question.  I'm currently using VSCode 1.88.1.)

Reported
